# monitor changes in mysql table and respond accordingly

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to monitor a particular mysql table for changes.
Suppose there is an insert command and I want to get the values of all the columns corresponding to that insert command and then use those values to do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) will handle detecting the insert for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_on_before_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON the_table_you_want_to_monitor
    ...
```

Comment: I want to get the phone of sender ,message and time from the insert command. Now using the data in the message I need to run another query to fetch the information from database. Suppose the message is the Sr.No of a person and I want to fetch the address of that person database using that Sr.No. and then run another mysql query to insert a new row in some other table in the same database. Is it possible using trigger?

Comment: Sure, the trigger has "context" of the row being inserted, so you can pull out the values and do things with them, including inserting into other tables. Look at the doc link I included in the answer. There's an example of an insert trigger taking the inserted values and putting them elsewhere.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. But if I wanted to do the same thing without using triggers ? what could be used for that ?

Comment: You'd have to poll the database with an external script regularly. Easier to implement/more portable, downside is you then need to be able to schedule that script so it triggers at a regular interval, and it'd have to handle multiple new rows. The trigger's internal, occurs automatically, but only handles one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I would try that. Seems like I would be asking more questions in couple of hours